# Quadratic Time to remove element in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

```
int lst_slow_remove_all(LIST *l, ElemType x) {
  int n=0;
  while(lst_remove_first(l, x))
    n++;
  return n;
}
```

function: **lst_sra_bad_case** (sra:  slow_remove_all)
description: constructs a list of length n such that 
the above function takes quadratic time to remove
all occurrences of a specified value. 
By convention, the specified value will be 0

```
LIST *lst_sra_bad_case(ElemType n)
```

There are cases for which the approach of **lst_slow_remove_all** takes time
proportional to n^2.

What is the bad case?

Comment: lst_remove_first(l, x) - removes first occurrence of x (if any). Returns 0 or 1 depending on whether x was found

Comment: l is list, and x is element to be removed. element with value x.

Comment: It sounds like one bad case is where every element past `n/2` is `x` and all of those prior are some other value.

Comment: Another possibility is where the data is "regular" in the sense that every possible value is consecutively placed

Comment: I don't think you are learning anything if you just ask stackoverflow for the answer.  What did you think of yourself?  Do you understand what the function does and how long it takes to run?  Have you stepped through a test case to see what happens when you have multiple items to be removed?  Did it make a difference where the items to be removed were located in the list?